# Remove node from Singly Linked List

Tags: javascript, singly-linked-list

I'm implementing a remove function for LL in Javascript.

Here's my function:

```js
//Define Node obj
function Node(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
}

//Define SinglyList obj
function SinglyList(){
  this._length = 0;
  this.head = null;
}

SinglyList.prototype.add = function(val){
  var node = new Node(val),
      currentNode = this.head;

      //If empty, build as first node
      if(!currentNode){
        this.head = node;
        this._length++;
        return;
      }

      //iterate over until end of list
      while(currentNode.next){
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }

      //add/append new node
      currentNode.next = node;
      this._length++;

      return node;
};

SinglyList.prototype.remove = function(index){
  var currentNode = this.head, count=0, previous;
  //if list is empty, exit out
  if(this._length===0) return;

  //Check if first node
  if(index===0){
      this.head = currentNode.next;
      this._length--;
  }else{

      while(count<index){
        previous = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        count++;
      }//end while

      previous.next = currentNode.next;

      return previous;
  }// end if

};

var singlyList = new SinglyList();

singlyList.add(1);
singlyList.add(2);
singlyList.add(3);
singlyList.add(4);
singlyList.add(5);
singlyList.add(6);
singlyList.add(7);
singlyList.add(8);
singlyList.add(9);
singlyList.add(10);

console.log(JSON.stringify(singlyList));
console.log('Remove:\n'+JSON.stringify(singlyList.remove(5)));
```

Problem: If i had 10 nodes in my list and called this function to remove 5th node, this function only returns 4th-10th nodes where 5th is removed. However, i'd expect it to return 1-10th where 5th is removed. What am i doing wrong and how can i retrieve a list where only the 5th node is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still
You made small mistake in your code

1) while loop should run till < index-1 as you are starting count at 0

2) You are not doing this._length-- after deleting node other than first

3) JSON.stringify starting printing with head element, when you are deleting node you are returning the previous node so you are getting wrong node list

The corrected code is here

```
//Define Node obj
function Node(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.next = null;
}

//Define SinglyList obj
function SinglyList(){
  this._length = 0;
  this.head = null;
}

SinglyList.prototype.add = function(val){
  var node = new Node(val),
      currentNode = this.head;

      //If empty, build as first node
      if(!currentNode){
        this.head = node;
        this._length++;
        return;
      }

      //iterate over until end of list
      while(currentNode.next){
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }

      //add/append new node
      currentNode.next = node;
      this._length++;

      return node;
};

SinglyList.prototype.remove = function(index){
  var currentNode = this.head, count=0, previous;
  //if empty, exit out
  if(this._length===0) return;

  //Check against first node
  if(index===0){
      this.head = currentNode.next;
      this._length--;
  }else{

      while(count<index-1){
        previous = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        count++;
      }//end while

      previous.next = currentNode.next;
      this._length--;

      return this.head;
  }// end if

};

var singlyList = new SinglyList();

singlyList.add(1);
singlyList.add(2);
singlyList.add(3);
singlyList.add(4);
singlyList.add(5);
singlyList.add(6);
singlyList.add(7);
singlyList.add(8);
singlyList.add(9);
singlyList.add(10);

document.write(JSON.stringify(singlyList));
singlyList.remove(5)
document.write('After removing 5 :\n'+JSON.stringify(singlyList));
```

Comment: I am sorry I am confuse whether you want to delete element with index 5 or value 5, if you want to delete index 5 then dont change while condition my code will delete element with value 5...

Comment: Holy crap! I've been staring at this past 3+ hrs. I still don't fully understand and i think i'm missing something fundamental in JS:
As i understood it, the "while loop" was there for iterating over and locating the target node while keeping a copy reference for previous node. Once the node is found and loop is completed, we are simply skipping over and pointing to next of next node. All of this..i get it.. however, what i don't understand is nowhere in this operation are we modifying original object stored in this.head so why is returning this.head returns the correct list?

Comment: i meant to remove by index

Comment: We dont modify any original node to delete other not even the head, head is modified only if we delete first node that is head itself. here we are just pointing pointer of fourth node to the sixth node and skipping fifth one.. to print all list JSON.stringify() should start at the head node which was missing in your code so you were getting wrong node list... element was deleting in your original code but list was displayed in wrong manner, and counter was not updated...

Comment: To delete index element dont follow my first point in original answer... :)

Comment: ah so the variables (currentNode, previous) we're using to achieve this operation do not necessarily house their own separate objects, they're just representing different portions of the original object in the memory eh?

Comment: They are working as a reference to the original objects of a list they are local variables and not tied to list, they are just referencing elements of list and going out of scope when function ends, but your list is intact till the end of your code..

Comment: Thanks @ghanshyam-bagul! This is instrumental in helping me build other operations: prepend, append etc.. hopefully this is helpful for others in the future too!